# mysql does not start with large log files

Tags: mysql, docker

The following container works as expected with the given config file. But if I increase the innodb_log_file_size to something 512 from current 419 then the container fails to start. How does the little extra space prohibit the container from starting?

```
docker run -v /my/custom:/etc/mysql/conf.d  -v /tmp/mydata/mysql:/var/lib/mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=abc -d mysql:5.5
```

cat /my/custom/config-file.cnf

```
[mysqld]
#datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/tmp/mysql.sock
user=root
#innodb_force_recovery=6
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2G
innodb_file_per_table=1
innodb_log_file_size=419M
#innodb_log_file_size=519M
innodb_log_buffer_size=500K
innodb_thread_concurrency=2
[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

Comment: add your starting console output, pls

Comment: Probably answered here http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1261/how-to-safely-change-mysql-innodb-variable-innodb-log-file-size

Comment: Can you post the log output when it fails to start?

Comment: It fails at line 51 of this file...https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/master/5.5/docker-entrypoint.sh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was because mysql waits for 30 seconds (only!) before exiting. Since creating larger log files takes time, we need to increase the check from 30 seconds to 180 seconds.

The change in source code can be viewed here...

https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/compare/master...shantanuo:master

I created another image with this change:

```
git clone https://github.com/shantanuo/mysql

cd mysql/5.5

docker build -t shantanuo/mysql .

docker push shantanuo/mysql
```

now test:

```
docker run -v /my/custom:/etc/mysql/conf.d  -v /tmp/mydata/mysql:/var/lib/mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=abc -d shantanuo/mysql
```